# Cardinality of a nested set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

What is the cardinality of {a,{b,{c,d,e},{f,{g}}}}?

I think it's 2 because the set length of the broadest {} is 2, but I am not sure if the set being nested will affect the cardinality.

Comment: $ \{\color{blue}{\underbrace a},\color{blue}{\{\underbrace{\color{green}{\underbrace b,\underbrace{\{\color{red}{\underbrace c,\underbrace d,\underbrace e}\}},\underbrace{\{\color{purple}{\underbrace f,{\underbrace{\{\color{orange}{\underbrace g}\}}}}\}}}\}}}\}$.  You have two (blue) things in the set.  Se the cardinality is $2$.

Answer (score 0):

The set has two elements: $a$ and $\{b,\{c,d,e\},\{f\{g\}\}\}$. Therefore its cardinality is 2.

The *type* of elements a set contains does not affects the set's cardinality. What matters is just the *number* of elements it contains.